# Computing yearperiod from date by comparing date column with two reference columns

Tags: python, apache-spark, date, pyspark

I'm working on some data preparation for a project I'm involved in. We do most of the work in Databricks, using the underlying Apache Spark for computations on large datasets. Everything is done in PySpark.

My goal is to convert a date variable to a variable `yearperiod`, which divides the year into 13 periods of 4 weeks (with some exceptions). The value is a concatenation of the year and the period, e.g. `yearperiod = 201513` would be the year 2015, period 13.

I have two tables: `yp_table` which contains start and end dates (Edit: type `DateType()`) for yearperiods (between 2012 and now, Edit: ~120 rows):

```
+----------+----------+----------+
|     start|       end|yearperiod|
+----------+----------+----------+
|2012-01-16|2012-01-29|    201201|
|2012-01-30|2012-02-26|    201202|
|2012-02-27|2012-03-25|    201203|
|2012-03-26|2012-04-22|    201204|
|2012-04-23|2012-05-20|    201205|
|2012-05-21|2012-06-17|    201206|
              ....
```

And I have the actual `data` table, which contains a Date column (Edit: type `StringType()`):

```
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|    Var1|    Var2|    Date| Var3|
+--------+--------+--------+-----+
|  xxxxxx|    xxxx|20191231| x,xx|
|  xxxxxx|    xxxx|20191231| x,xx|
|  xxxxxx|    xxxx|20191231| x,xx|
|  xxxxxx|    xxxx|20200101| x,xx|
|  xxxxxx|    xxxx|20200101| x,xx|
|  xxxxxx|    xxxx|20200101| x,xx|
|  xxxxxx|    xxxx|20200101| x,xx|
                 ...
```

My question: how do I compute a column `yearperiod` for the `data` table, by comparing `data.Date` with both `yp_table.start` and `yp_table.end`?

So far I've been able to make it work with regular Python (a solution with list comprehensions), but it proves to be too slow for large datasets. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: for privacy reasons I can't give the actual schemas of the dataframes. I've edited above to include the types of the relevant columns.

Comment: `yp_table` is pretty small, isnt it ? like ~100 lines

Comment: what is the schema of the tables ? can you show `data.printSchema()` and `yp_table.printSchema()`?

Comment: In the future please provide a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example. My solution below illustrates how you could have posted this in a way that someone can copy-paste and run an example.

Comment: @Steven, yes, around 120 lines. I'd rather not give the full schemas for the dfs. I've provided types for the relevant columns though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a column to your `data` df that contains the dates in the matching format to the `yp_table` and then join them filtering by date intervals. Since the `yp_table` is small, you can use a broadcast join to speed things up.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as fun

# Date lookup
start_dates = ["2012-01-16", "2012-01-30", "2012-02-27", "2012-03-26", "2012-04-23", "2012-05-21"]
end_dates = ["2012-01-29", "2012-02-26", "2012-03-25", "2012-04-22", "2012-05-20", "2012-06-17"]
yearperiod = ["201201", "201202", "201203", "201204", "201205", "201206"]
yp_table = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'start': start_dates, 'end': end_dates, 'yearperiod': yearperiod}))

# Data df
dates =  ["20120116", "20120130", "20120228", "20120301", "20200101", "20200101", "20200101"]
vals = range(0, len(dates))

data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'Dates':dates, 'vals': vals}))

# Add formatted data_str column for joining
data = data.withColumn("date_str", fun.concat_ws("-", data.Dates.substr(0,4), data.Dates.substr(5,2), data.Dates.substr(7,2))) # + "-" + data.Dates.substr(6,8))

# Broadcase join small yp_table into the data table using conditional
joined = data.join(fun.broadcast(yp_table), (data.date_str >= yp_table.start) & (data.date_str < yp_table.end))


yp_table.show()
data.show()
joined.show()

+----------+----------+----------+
|     start|       end|yearperiod|
+----------+----------+----------+
|2012-01-16|2012-01-29|    201201|
|2012-01-30|2012-02-26|    201202|
|2012-02-27|2012-03-25|    201203|
|2012-03-26|2012-04-22|    201204|
|2012-04-23|2012-05-20|    201205|
|2012-05-21|2012-06-17|    201206|
+----------+----------+----------+

+--------+----+----------+
|   Dates|vals|  date_str|
+--------+----+----------+
|20120116|   0|2012-01-16|
|20120130|   1|2012-01-30|
|20120228|   2|2012-02-28|
|20120301|   3|2012-03-01|
|20200101|   4|2020-01-01|
|20200101|   5|2020-01-01|
|20200101|   6|2020-01-01|
+--------+----+----------+

+--------+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|   Dates|vals|  date_str|     start|       end|yearperiod|
+--------+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|20120116|   0|2012-01-16|2012-01-16|2012-01-29|    201201|
|20120130|   1|2012-01-30|2012-01-30|2012-02-26|    201202|
|20120228|   2|2012-02-28|2012-02-27|2012-03-25|    201203|
|20120301|   3|2012-03-01|2012-02-27|2012-03-25|    201203|
+--------+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I realize I didn't specify clearly enough, but the `start` and `end` columns are of type `DateType()`. By converting the `data.Date` column to type `DateType()` using `to_date`, this solution works! Marking as accepted.

Comment: Yup, that is why the MCVEs are so powerful It forces you to think through and specify all the details of your problem. To be honest I end up answering my own question through the process of creating the MCVE about 80% of the time. Bad for SO points but good for personal agency, lol